# NullPointerException when calling a method

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

Getting a NullPointerException when calling method fillDBWeek(String mName). I can not spot where I am going wrong can some one please help me?

This is the error I am getting for the following method

```
*Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at View.LectureReport.fillDBWeek(LectureReport.java:49)
    at View.LectureReport$2.actionPerformed(LectureReport.java:96)*
```

Method fillDBWeek

```
public void fillDBWeek(String mName)
    {
         tableModel.setDataVector(lRHand.popuSDataWeek(mName), columnNames);
         table.setModel(tableModel);
         table.repaint(); 
    }
```

Where the method is called when pressing button

```
JButton btnViewReport = new JButton("View Report");
    btnViewReport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String moduleName = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            if(comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().equals("Week"))
            {
                fillDBWeek(moduleName);
            }
            else if (comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().equals("Semester"))
            {
                fillDBSem(moduleName);
            }
            else if (comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().equals("Year"))
            {
                fillDBYear(moduleName);
            }
        }
    });
```

Query using to call the data from SQL database

```
public Object[][] popuSDataWeek(String moduleName)
{
    data = new Object[30][9];

    try{
           Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS);

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url,"polk", "mire");

            statement = connection.createStatement();
            results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Group6_StudAttWeek WHERE module = '"+ moduleName +"'");
            int i=0;
            while(results.next())
            {
            data[i][0]= results.getString("firstname");
            data[i][1]= results.getString("lastname");
            data[i][2]= results.getString("module");
            data[i][3] = results.getString("yearOfStudy");
            data[i][4]= results.getInt("workshop%");
            data[i][5]= results.getInt("tutorial%");
            data[i][6] = results.getInt("lecture%");
            data[i][7] = results.getInt("avg%");
            data[i][8] = results.getInt("number");
            i++;
            }
       results.close();
       statement.close();
       connection.close();
       } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
       sqlException.printStackTrace();
       System.exit(1);
       }catch(Exception exception) {
       System.err.println("An error happened");
       System.exit(1);
       }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Based on the stack, if the exception rises in `fillDBWeek` and not in `popuSDataWeek`, then either the `tableModel` or the `table` are null. If the exception is thrown by `popuSDataWeek` the only probable null object I see is `connection`. Did you debug your application to check those three possibilities?.

Comment: and youi don´t get any other Exeption? Is it an Exeption, coming up while you are in your Program, or do you catch this Nullpointer?

Comment: @Gamb Yes the tableModel was not declared, Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which of these is null: tableModel, mName, table, lRHand ... do some debugging and you'll find it

Comment: @user1873139 Glad to know, I've elaborated my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stack:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at View.LectureReport.fillDBWeek(LectureReport.java:49)
    at View.LectureReport$2.actionPerformed(LectureReport.java:96)
```

The exception rises in `fillDBWeek`, either because `tableModel` or `table` are null. If the exception is thrown by `popuSDataWeek`, instead, it should be present on the stacktrace, but anyway the only probable null object I see is `connection`.

Please, make sure the proper objects are declared and initialized before using them.